# Django + NGINX URL Problem

Tags: django, url, nginx

I have set up Django's FastCGI + NGINX, but it's only working for root url: any request to `http://example.com/anything` redirects to `http://example.com`. Django's internal server working fine, NGINX static file serving and FastCGI processing of the root URL is fine, error log is clear. Here is my config's server section:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  example.com;

        location / {
              fastcgi_pass localhost:8000;
              include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location /static/ {
              alias /root/web_development/src/web_development/static/;
        }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the content of fastcgi_params?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this configs:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;

        location / {
                root /home/example.com/foo;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8000;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
                fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
                fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
                fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
                fastcgi_pass_header Authorization;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        }
}
```

Make sure you've already informed nginx the port which django runs.

Comment: It's definitely working! Thank you! The problem was in the absence of `PATH_INFO` parameter in `fastcgi_params`.

Comment: Isn't this setup passing all files through fastcgi? Seems to me that only php files should be matched while other resources should be served directly.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to add this line to location /:

```
fastcgi_split_path_info ^()(.*)$;
```

from [djangoandnginx](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoAndNginx)