# Django's URL regex engine is failing

Tags: regex, django, nginx, django-urls

Django's URL regex engine is failing and I have no idea why. Even my sanity checks are failing horribly.

Here's my `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^a', 'placemyorder.views.home', name='home'),
)
```

I get this 404 error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://[ip address]/a/
Using the URLconf defined in placemyorder.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
1. ^a [name='home']
The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
```

when I visit

`http://[ip address]/a`

And it's hosted on Django 1.5.2 with Python 2.7.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 behind nginx if that info is relevant.

Comment: Did you try `r'^a/$'` ?

Comment: Yes I tried that with the same result

Comment: what does your root urls.py look like? Please paste the code, rather than the screenshots of code

Comment: same exact result `1. ^a$ [name='home']`

Comment: Is that your root urls.py file contents ?

Comment: what happens if you try `http://[ip address]/placemyorder/a/` ?

Comment: that doesn't work either. same exact result but the request url section says `Request URL: http://[ip address]/placemyorder/a/`

Comment: Did you try r'^a/'  without the dollar sign ?

Comment: Yes, with the same page as above with `1. ^a/ [name='home']`

Comment: Does ANY url work? try to assign your template to `'^$'` and see if that flies.

Comment: Yes and if I use `'^$'` then any urls defined afterward will just get caught in the default `'^$'`

Comment: When I try a nonexistent url, I get `Using the URLconf defined in urlconf,...` not `<appname>.urlconf`. Are you sure this is urls.py is in your root?

Comment: Yes because I don't have any apps installed, there's nowhere else for it to be. I'm just starting out with this project and I already messed it up!

Comment: Wait a second, here's a clue `The current URL, , didn't match any of these.` It should say `The current URL, http://[ip address]/a, didn't match any of these.` So the dispatcher isn't getting the request url. Could that be an nginx issue?

Comment: I think you're right. I tried the code on a different machine with `python manage.py runserver 8080` and it parsed the url correctly. I'm still researching how to fix it though...

Comment: I think I know what the problem is now. I wish I had thought about nginx being the problem. Rob L maybe you could "answer" this question so I can mark it? Your suggestion led me to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104723/django-nginx-url-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a clue: `The current URL, , didn't match any of these.`

It should say: `The current URL, http://[ip address]/a, didn't match any of these.`

So the dispatcher isn't getting the request url.

Take a look at this solution:
[Django + NGINX URL Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104723/django-nginx-url-problem)